# Ajax call to form field to auto-populate other fields

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms

I am using python django and regular html form
So i had a very specific situation where I have a form and it builds "Menus" for food programs
in the Menus it has meal types: BreakFast, AM snack, lunch, supper etc..
per meal type there are components: grain, veg, fruit, meat, beverage

a unitized meal is built up of food items and components.
when user chooses unitized meal (component: meat and fruit)

how can i construct a way when i choose a unitized meal, it auto populates the Meat and fruit fields of the form, based on the items of the unitized meals..

all my models with many-to-many fields are linked proper i just need to know what kind of way can i approach this.

if any additional code is needed please let me know
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRGjc.png)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#unitized').on('change', function(){
        var url = "{% url 'ajax_unitized_meals' %}"
        console.log($(this).val())
        var id = $(this).val()
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            data: {'unitized' : id},
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

```html
<div id="mealpatterns">
    {% for mealtype,component in distinct_values.items %}
        <h2>
            Meal Type: {{mealtype}}
            <hr>
        </h2>
        {% if mealtype == 'Breakfast' or mealtype == 'Lunch' or mealtype == 'Supper' %}
        <h4>Unitized Meal</h4>
        <select id="unitized" class="select"  placeholder='choose unitized meal' class="form-control input-lg">
            {%for item in unitized%}
            <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
            {%endfor%}
        </select>
        {% endif %}
        {% for component in component %}
            <h4>

                <h4>Component: {{component}}</h4>

                <!-- carlos old loop -->
                {% comment %}
                {% if dictionary_components|get_item:v %}
                <select class="select"  placeholder='choose item' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                    <!-- these are the fields in that component AKA name -->
                    {%for x in dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                        <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{x}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}
                </select>
                {%endif%}
                {% endcomment %}
                <!-- end carlos old loop -->

            {% if component == 'Beverage' %}
            <select class="select" placeholder='choose beverage' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                {%for item in  dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>

            {% endif %}

            {% if component == 'Fruit' %}
            <select class="select" placeholder='choose fruit' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                {%for item in  dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

            {% if component == 'Grain' %}
            <select class="select" placeholder='choose grain' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                {%for item in  dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

            {% if component == 'Vegetable' %}
            <select class="select" placeholder='choose vegetable' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                {%for item in  dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

            {% if component == 'Meat/Meat Alternative' %}
            <select class="select" placeholder='choose meat/meat alternative' class="form-control input-lg" multiple>
                {%for item in  dictionary_components|get_item:component %}
                <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{item}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

        </h4>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- just leave this table tag here for selectize to work -->
        </table


</div>

<div id="start_here">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select').selectize({
        sortField: 'text'
    });
});
</script>

def ajaxUnitizedMeals(request):
    unitized = request.GET['unitized']
    print(f'unitized before: {unitized}')
    unitized = prodModels.UnitizedMeals.objects.all().values()
    print(f'unitized meal: {unitized}')
    unitized = prodModels.UnitizedMeals.objects.filter(items__components__name=unitized)
    # print(f'unitized items: {unitized}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps.

Create a view to receive the ajax request and return the value as HTML(You may also return as JSON).

Call the ajax query function on change of the unitized meal.

Something like:

If 'unitized_meal' is the id of your unitized meal

```
$('unitized_meal').change(function(){
$.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'view_name_here' %}",
      type: "POST",
      data: { unitized_meal: $("#unitized_meal").val(),
              //csrf token here for method POST
            },
      dataType: "html"
    });
```

})

Let me know if it helps .

Comment: yes i have already done that.. i need help on the logic that goes in the view..